# How can I print graphics on a roll of tape with a printer?

Tags: print-design

I want to save money by printing my own repeated graphic on a long strip of reinforced water-activated paper tape (the stuff Amazon uses). I just don't know if I can create a file with the dimensions of the tape, say, 2" by 35', and then repeat the graphics all the way down, and then print with a custom size. Aren't there limits to the size of material? Do I need a special printer or can I hack mine? I have a Xerox Phaser.

Comment: Most printer drivers allow you to ask for NN copies so just need one image... After that its just a matter of defining the page size to get the required spacing.

Comment: @xenoid, oh, you're saying 240 copies of the same, say, 2" by 5" logo on a continuous roll of 2" by 100' with no breaks?

Comment: You will not be able to print using the Xerox Phaser. I am not sure what type of printer they use but I would imagine they print on a large wide roll and then cut the tape into 2" strips afterwards (just a guess). When printing on a roll paper, you're only limited to the length of the roll of paper. In my print shop we sometimes send prints that are 140' long.

Comment: I may have found a work around. Cut the tape to 2" by 12" strips, and print individually in a stack.

Comment: FYI, I don't _need_ to save money. I just _like_ to save money.